# Connect ESP32/ESP8266 to domain website to control LED's

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266, esp32

I was wondering if there is any way to connect the ESP32/ESP8266 to my domain in Hostgator, I have a website which has buttons to control LED's or other stuff connected to the ESP, but I was searching to see if it is possible to connect the ESP to my website, I can only see videos and documentation of the ESP creating it's on WebServer, Is there any way to connect it to my domain Website?

Comment: you can communicate with the web server, making GET requests to URLs where you return data for the esp

Comment: Please add web protocol detail: Does your web site use HTTPS (Secure) vs. HTTP (insecure)? Does that web input page - the page with the buttons - perform a GET request, vs. a POST request?

If you don't know, that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

If your web site uses HTTPS you can find a useful example in the ESP8266 Arduino code. See the [HTTPSRequest](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/HTTPSRequest/HTTPSRequest.ino) example .ino file.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set your ESP has an access Point, you can see how to it here https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/soft-access-point-class.html
Then in your website you need to make a POST request to your ESP IP. Considering you're not using any type of Back-End you do not need to connect your ESP to the Website but the other way around. Hope this gave you a little help

Comment: how should esp running as access point connect to server in Internet?

Comment: You right he just needs to make is ESP IP open to the outside has STATION of course, I was not thinking the right way. But the best option is using MQTT instead of HTTP in my option.

Answer (score 0):

Making HTTP request from ESP8266 board is very simple and straight-forward process.

You can look at the WebClient example that is installed with the ESP8266 library.

Then - after you craft the URL you're querying and you know the format of the answer you get - you just test for it to decide what to do with your LEDs.

Please let know if there is a need for more clarifications or code sample.